selenium python code executes perfectly in geany but not in terminal - hence not in autostart
I am using a python script to communicate between various raspi devices and my server. I want to create a python backend that handles settings communicated to it by my server.
So far this part works well, but now I want to have python call different websites, that the server tells it to.
So if the server says open google, then the local script should navigate the current browser to google, if a new website is sent, it should go there.
This way I can manage various displays in my network and use a server to chose which websites each display will present.
After a bunch of searching and browsing for a good solution I came to various guides that bascially lead me to this setup:

pip3 install selenium==3.8.0 --break-system-packages


sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

This is my code, and when running it directly out of geany it works perfectly.
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument("--noerrdialogs")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--show-taps")
options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
print("opening chrome...")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
print("opening first website")
driver.get("http://selenium.dev")
print("opening second website")
driver.get("http://funtech-entertainment.com")
print("done")

However, when running it our of terminal (which I need for autostart) it does not work at all, the screen just freezes, untill I relieve the system by AltF4 killing the task. I added the Prints to see where it gets stuck, and it stops after "opening chrome...". Below you see the terminal message after ALTF4.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 /home/pi/FunTechKiosk/KioskDriver.py
opening chrome...
opening first website
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/FunTechKiosk/KioskDriver.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver.get("http://selenium.dev")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 323, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=130.0.6723.58)

